# Conditional formatting script - set iteration

Tags: google-sheets, formatting, conditional-statements

I have a custom formula for conditional formatting rules. I am trying to write a script that checks a number of values (around 50) on a column (column B on 'Mine' sheet) and if a cell is equal to a specific string (M1, M2 or M3) then the specified formula for conditional formatting is applied to the "Calendar view" sheet. The code I currently have is:

```
function myFunction() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Calendar View");
sheet.getRange("C4:NC50").clearFormat();
var range = sheet.getRange("C4:NC4");
var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
    .whenFormulaSatisfied('=AND(indirect("Mine!$B5")="M1", C$2>=indirect("Mine!$C5"), C$2<indirect("Mine!$D5"))')
    .setBackground("#FF0000")
    .setRanges([range])
    .build();
var rules = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
rules.push(rule);
sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(rules);
}
```

How can I enter an iteration method on the .whenFormulaSatisfied, such as:

```
.whenFormulaSatisfied('=AND(indirect("Mine!$B6")="M1", C$2>=indirect("Mine!$C6"), C$2<indirect("Mine!$D6"))')
.whenFormulaSatisfied('=AND(indirect("Mine!$B7")="M1", C$2>=indirect("Mine!$C7"), C$2<indirect("Mine!$D7"))')
.whenFormulaSatisfied('=AND(indirect("Mine!$B8")="M1", C$2>=indirect("Mine!$C8"), C$2<indirect("Mine!$D8"))')
............
```

This is the sheet I'm working on:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Af84aHaG0VjXmtaWc0-uAdGFrX1LozRNLQLMatSOqgU/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some challenges to the questioner's methodology - first, the dynamic identification of the start and end dates for each property, and second, the creation of up to 50 separate Conditional Formatting rules. It's well known that spreadsheet performance is affected by numbers of Conditional Formatting rules.

I'm suggesting a slightly different approach.
1) Take the data on Mine and build the Calendar.
2) Place values in the booked date fields.
3) Apply a **single** Conditional Formatting rule for Calendar.

The methodology for identifying which dates are booked is to insert a nominal value in the respective cells. Then the rule `.whenCellNotEmpty()` is applied rather than specifying a specific value. In addition, the code formats both the background as well as the font colour so that any data is hidden.

Also to note: at the beginning of the script, the code removes both the content as well as the formatting.

```
function so_53185335() {
    // build the spreadsheet app and set source and target sheets
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var calSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Calendar View");
    var dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Mine");

    // get the last rows and start rows for both sheets 
    var lrMine = dataSheet.getLastRow();
    var lrCal = calSheet.getLastRow();
    var dataRowStart = 5;
    var calRowStart = 4;

    // clear formats and data from Calendar  
    calSheet.getRange(calRowStart, 2, lrCal, 366).clear({
        contentsOnly: true,
        formatOnly: true
    });

    // get Mine rows with data, define the range and  get data
    var dataRows = lrMine - dataRowStart + 1;
    //Logger.log("Mine: number of data rows "+dataRows);// DEBUG  
    var dataRange = dataSheet.getRange(dataRowStart, 2, dataRows, 3);
    //Logger.log("data range is "+dataRange.getA1Notation());// DEBUG
    var dataValues = dataRange.getValues();

    //set some variables for use in loop  
    var i = 0; // counter
    var z = 0; // counter
    var calstartCol = 3; // equals first day of the year
    var calrow = 0; // counter row for Calendar sheet
    var calArray = [];
    var masterArray = [];

    // loop through the rows in Mine

    for (i = 0; i < dataRows; i++) {
        // test for value 
        if (dataValues[i][0] === "M1" || dataValues[i][0] === "M2" || dataValues[i][0] === "M3") {
            //Logger.log("Match: i="+i+", value = "+dataValues[i][0]);//DEBUG
            calArray = [];
            masterArray = [];
            calrow = calrow + 1;

            // calculate the start day (as a day in the year)
            var now = new Date(dataValues[i][1]);
            var start = new Date(now.getFullYear(), 0, 0);
            var diff = (now - start) + ((start.getTimezoneOffset() - now.getTimezoneOffset()) * 60 * 1000);
            var oneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
            var startday = Math.floor(diff / oneDay);

            // calculate the end day (as a day in the year)
            var fnow = new Date(dataValues[i][2]);
            var fstart = new Date(fnow.getFullYear(), 0, 0);
            var fdiff = (fnow - fstart) + ((fstart.getTimezoneOffset() - fnow.getTimezoneOffset()) * 60 * 1000);
            var foneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
            var endday = Math.floor(fdiff / foneDay);
            var nod = endday - startday + 1;

            // assign the value for the Property
            var cell = calSheet.getRange(calstartCol + calrow, 2);
            cell.setValue(dataValues[i][0]);

            // create an array of values for booked dates; just insert the number "1"
            for (z = 1; z < nod + 1; z++) {
                calArray.push(1);
            }
            masterArray.push(calArray);

            // Assign the values for booked dates
            var cell = calSheet.getRange(calstartCol + calrow, startday + 2, 1, nod);
            cell.setValue(masterArray);
        }

    }

    // create and apply a single Conditional forma rule for the data range on Calendar
    var range = calSheet.getRange(calRowStart, calstartCol, calstartCol + calrow, 366);
    var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
        .whenCellNotEmpty()
        .setFontColor("#FF0000")
        .setBackground("#FF0000")
        .setRanges([range])
        .build();
    var rules = calSheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
    rules.push(rule);
    calSheet.setConditionalFormatRules(rules);

}
```

The Calendar looks like this.

---

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! Your approach sounds great, I could already see the spreadsheet struggling to cope with a few conditional formatting rules. I just tried it on the above test spreadsheet but I get the following error: "The coordinates or dimensions of the range are invalid. (line 70, file "test macro")", on this line: var cell = calSheet.getRange(calstartCol + calrow, startday + 2, 1, nod);

Comment: @Spyr Your original Spreadsheet had a Locale of Finland and TimeZone of Helsinki (GMT+2), and the original Project Time Zone was also Helsinki (GMT+2). Presently your Spreadsheet Locale=United Kingdom, Spreadsheet Time Zone=Helsinki (GMT+2) and  (significantly) Project Time Zone=Eastern  (GMT-5). Edit your Spreadsheet settings and the Project settings so that they all have the same Time Zone; I'd also adjust the Locale too. Fix those and re-run - should be OK.